# HTML agility pack for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

I am still trying programming for windows phone 8.1 but I have a little problem. I want parse HTML data and I found one tutorial for better mind this tutorial = [click here](http://www.tareqateik.com/html-agility-pack%E2%80%93windows-phone-8#.U7mCqPl_t2l);
but It works great only in windows phone 7/8 with HTMLAgility pack. I tried manual add library but versions  sl3-wp, winrt45 don't support method:

```
htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'list_item')]"));
```

and version for wp7 doesn't work too. Any Ideas how to parse data for WP 8.1 ? thank you in advance (And sorry for my bad English :) )

Comment: So, you try to run a library that is not supported on windows phone on windows phone and wonder why it does not run? Is that sort of summing it up?

Comment: No, I did use library fow WP7 and WP8 and I need it work on WP8.1 or If exist another solution it should be perfect :)

Comment: Have you tried making your own build for the target platform you need?

Comment: No because I am still beginner for this platform and I think that exist solution for my problem.

Comment: I only want know If exist HTML agility pack for this platform or another solution for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Since HTML agility pack wasn't supported using Universal Apps I got their source code from codeplex and created a new library just for universal Apps.
You can get the binary and the source in my [New Blog](http://devproj.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/html-agility-pack-universal-apps/#more-7)

I'm just starting with this blogging thing but may this may be useful until the team provides an official release.

Comment: Wow! That's perfect. One question: It doesn't have SelectNodes(), what's the workaround!

Comment: Use LINQ on Descendants()

Answer (score 0):

HTML agility pack is still not supported in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime or Universal App project. But the above solution will work on Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

Click on Blank App (Silverlight) and target it to Windows Phone 8.1. Add the libraries HTTP client, html agility pack. Also look for "System.Xml.Xpath.dll for Silverlight 4" in the Nuget manager and install that. Add the references and the code should work.