# HTML parser for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: html, parsing, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I'm a iOS developer starting to learn Windows Phone. My project is targeted for 8 and 8.1 and it's about parsing a HTML document. I found a library named HTMLAgilityPack which is most used to parse HTML, but it is not supported for 8.1 version. So i tried to find another way to parse my HTML document and could not find any help online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using HtmlAgilityPack-PCL which can be accessed [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack-PCL/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `HtmlAgilityPack` using `Linq`? 
[HtmlAgilityPack using Linq for windows phone 8.1 platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261194/)

But as far as i know `HtmlAgilityPack` doesn't support any 8.1 apps for WP. But the blog mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598363/html-agility-pack-for-windows-phone-8-1) thread has mentioned about using this parser for `Universal` apps.